# Picasso with OkHttp?

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

How to write picasso with Okhttp?

My code is given below but it is showing Error. By the way I am having confusion that picasso uses by default OkHttp or should I write it in code also?

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient)).build();
OkHttpDownloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(downloader).build();
Picasso.with(context).load("http://192.168.0.15:1337/offers/" + image_url.get(position)).resize(350, 100).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to do things like that. OkHttp is a thing, which just make HTTP connection and loading files, for example, JSON easier. You should use it in separate thread, otherwise, you'll get an `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

If you just need to download image, you won't need specific HTTP connection. Just use Picasso, for example, in `onCreate()` of the Activity, and enjoy the result.

All you need to do is:

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load("http://192.168.0.15:1337/offers/" + image_url.get(position))
       .resize(350, 100)
       .centerCrop()
       .into(holder.imageView);
```